# как обойти защиту ботов Cloudflare в selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
url_1 = "https://bot.sannysoft.com/"
option = webdriver.Fire fox Options()
option.set_preference(
"general.useragent.override",
"Mozilla/4.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 YaBrowser/21.8.3.614 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
```

)

```
option.set_preference('useAutomationExtension', False)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=option, executable_path='C:/Users/Dima/Desktop/firefoxdriver/geckodriver.exe')
browser.get(url_1)
```

[image: сайт не пропускает пробовал time sleep(10)]

Comment: использую selenium firefox буду признателен за помощь

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: undetected_chromedriver попробуй воспользоваться данной библиотекой

Answer (score 2):

Встречался с такой проблемой, и гуглил такое решение:

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r"webdriver\chromedriver.exe")
```

Оригинал: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67341346/how-to-bypass-cloudflare-bot-protection-in-selenium

Comment: спасибо помогло